# Mysql joins problem

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I use this query to select all articles :

```
SELECT articles.*,categories.category_name,users.username,tags.tag 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON articles.category_id = categories.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.author_id = users.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON articles.article_id = tags.article_id 
ORDER BY articles.date_added DESC
```

I have an other table `comments`, and I want to count how many comments are there, where the article_id in that table = article_id in the articles table. I tried with COUNT, but then it returns only one result. How can I do that with one query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT articles.*,categories.category_name,users.username,tags.tag, (SELECT count(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.article_id = articles.article_id) as comments_count
```

Answer (score 0):

As arnaud576875 already stated, you can use a subquery to extract the summary data.

Two things I've noticed from your SQL that are not really a part of the question but still worth pointing out.

- you can use a table alias to shorten your SQL and make it more readable.

So instead of

```
SELECT articles.*,categories.category_name,users.username,tags.tag 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON articles.category_id = categories.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.author_id = users.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `tags` ON articles.article_id = tags.article_id 
ORDER BY articles.date_added DESC
```

you'd code

```
SELECT a.*, c.category_name, u.username, t.tag 
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN `categories` c ON a.category_id = c.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON a.author_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `tags` t ON a.article_id = t.article_id 
ORDER BY a.date_added DESC
```

- I would drop SELECT * and select only the fields that you actually are going to use. This also helps with readability of your code.